# How automatically to run node js (express) app on live server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server

I have express app like backend side for my Angular app. How can I deploy that app on remote server and that app always works on server ?

Answer (score 1):

Some say it is not a good idea to run node as your server directly and some say it doesn't matter. Anyways:

There are multiple ways you could achieve this:

### Docker

Create a Dockerfile based on node, copy over your application and start your built image as a container with restart (docker-service). It could be something like this (very much simplified):

```
FROM node:latest
COPY ./app:/APP_DIRECTORY
RUN node /APP_DIRECTORY/index.js
```

### systemd (on Linux systems)

Create a service directly on your OS and let it restart automatically. More on this: https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/

### pm2

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/you-should-never-ever-run-directly-against-node-js-in-production-maybe-7fdfaed51ec6/

You could think of the recommendation to use nginx as a proxy for your node application. More on this here (this link has also an example for pm2): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

---

## EDIT: 2020-01-27

## Example with fastify and pm2

Since the author of this question wanted me to provide an example with pm2, here we go:

### Prerequesites

```
mkdir pm2-test
cd pm2-test
npm init -y
npm install --save fastify
npm install --save-dev nodemon
npm install -g pm2
touch index.js
```

### Create the server

```
// package.json -> scripts section
[...]
"scripts": {
  "start": "pm2 start index.js",
  "dev": "nodemon index.js"
},
[...]

// index.js -> copied from fastify's example on github
// Require the framework and instantiate it
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  logger: true
})

// Declare a route
fastify.get('/', (request, reply) => {
  reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
})

// Run the server!
fastify.listen(3000, (err, address) => {
  if (err) throw err
  fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`)
})
```

### Start pm2 process(es)

```
npm start
```

### Result

```
// in console:
╰─ npm start

> pm2-test@1.0.0 start /Volumes/Samsung_T5/private/pm2-test
> pm2 start index.js

[PM2] Starting /Volumes/Samsung_T5/private/pm2-test/index.js in 
fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.

/** SOME BIG TABLE DISPLAYS ALL OF YOUR RUNNING/STOPPED INSTANCES **/

// In the browser -> localhost:3000
{ "hello": "world" }
```

Comment: please could you share all steps for run express server using `pm2`, because after I run express server with `pm2` and when I tried to make API call to that server by Angular app, I can see that server hasn't run. Thank you

Comment: Done. Edited my answer - good luck!